# Escape tabs characters

Tags: postgresql

In my Postrges table I have a column `reason` that is a `varchar` and I need to use its vaue to populate a `jsonb` column `reasons`.

I'm using a query like:

```
UPDATE table
SET reasons = ('{"' || reason || '": ' || amount::text || '}')::jsonb
```

I am getting an error telling me that I need to escape the 0x09 (tab) character, because some `reason` fields contain a tab column.

How can I escape the `reason` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to replace tab characters to spaces:

```
UPDATE a_table
SET reasons = ('{"' || replace(reason, e'\t', ' ') || '": ' || amount::text || '}')::jsonb
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a string which is guaranteed to be parse-able for `json` & `jsonb`, use [`to_json()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) (available from 9.3):

(And use `coalesce()`, if your columns can contain `NULL`s.)

```
UPDATE table
SET    reasons = ('{' || to_json(COALESCE(reason, '')) || ':' || COALESCE(to_json(amount), 'null') || '}')::jsonb
```

Or, use `json_build_object()` (available from 9.4):

```
UPDATE table
SET    reasons = json_build_object(COALESCE(reason, ''), amount)::jsonb
```

From 9.5, you will be able to directly build `jsonb` with [`jsonb_build_object()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html):

```
UPDATE table
SET    reasons = jsonb_build_object(COALESCE(reason, ''), amount)
```